Very basic Question regarding quotients of free abelian groups
I recently stumbled upon this something that I found a little bit confusing. So say we have some finite free abelian group B of rank m, so we have an expression of B as the direct sum $B = \mathbb{Z}x_1 \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}x_m$. Let $p$ be prime, then the quotient $B/pB$ is a direct sum of cyclic groups of order $p$. I guess my question would be why? Is this saying that we can do $B/pB \cong \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} \oplus \dots \oplus \mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z} $ (m times)? If so, why can we do this? I havent seen something like this before but in my book is seemed assumed like it was some common fact.

You can easily write an explicit isomorphism

@lhf I guess im confused on what $ pB$ looks like, thats my problem

@froitmi What confusion could there be? It consists by definition of all $p$-fold multiples of elements of $B$. In particular it contains $px_1, \ldots, px_m$.

Since $B\cong\mathbb{Z}^m$, $pB\cong p\mathbb{Z}^m$.
Consider the following homomorphism:
$$\varphi :\mathbb{Z}^m\rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^m\\
(x_1,...,x_m)\mapsto (x_1 \text{mod}\, p,...,x_m \text{mod}\, p)$$
the kernel of this homomorphism is $\text{Ker}(\varphi)=p\mathbb{Z}^m$, and the map is clearly surjective. Thus by the isomorphism theorem we have
$$B/pB\cong\mathbb{Z}^m/p\mathbb{Z}^m \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^m $$
